# Class Library Namespace Hierarchy Not Working

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, class-library

I am trying to achieve the namespace hierarchy used in C# in my class library. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
namespace Parent
{
    namespace Child
    {
        Class ChildClass {  }
    }

    Class ParentClass {  }
}
```

After compiling the class library It did not work as expected. Here is my expected working principle.

To access the `ChildClass` one has to `using Parent.Child`. But one can access `ParentClass` just by `using Parent`.

I can do this without compiling the class library but adding the cs file to the project. But when I compile as DLL and add it as a reference in a project I can't access the sub-namespaces.

UPDATE: I have different files for each class. When I write all namespaces and classes into one file it seems to work. But why?

Is there anyway to achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your classes missing `public`; Following code works for me.

```
namespace Parent
{
    namespace Child
    {
        public class ChildClass { }
    }
    public class ParentClass
    {
    }
}
```

I can create;

```
Parent.ParentClass p;
Parent.Child.ChildClass c;
```

Which is your expected working principle.

EDIT: separate cs file for each class approach;

**ParentClass.cs**

```
namespace Parent
{
    public class ParentClass{ }
}
```

**ChildClass.cs**

```
namespace Parent
{
    namespace Child
    {
        public class ChildClass { }
    }
}
```

This seems to be working for me.

Comment: Did you try this after compiling the class library?

Comment: I have multiple files. That seems to be the problem. Can you explain why?

Comment: Each class in separate file?

Comment: Separate class seems to be fine too.

Comment: Can you send me your sample project. Email: noor.xbyte@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting classes and namespaces and it all seems a little confused. Why don't you keep a flatter namespace structure and do the nesting in your classes. Keep in mind that you don't need to nest namespaces or classes to maintain a parent child relationship.

Have a read of the following: [Parent child class relationship design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630987/parent-child-class-relationship-design-pattern)

This should get you started in the right direction:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class ChildClass
    {
        private ParentClass parent;

        public ChildClass(ParentClass parentIn)
        {
            parent = parentIn;
        }

        public ParentClass Parent
        {
            get { return parent; }
        }
    }

    public class ParentClass
    {
        private List<ChildClass> children;

        public ParentClass()
        {
            children = new List<ChildClass>();
        }

        public ChildClass AddChild()
        {
            var newChild = new ChildClass(this);
            children.Add(newChild);
            return newChild;
        }
    }


    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

            var p = new ParentClass();
            var firstChild = p.AddChild();
            var anotherChild = p.AddChild();
            var firstChildParent = firstChild.Parent;
            var anotherChildParent = anotherChild.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```